# Grinding noise from brakes

Tags: brakes, mitsubishi, grinding, lancer

Lancer 2005 es non-abs

I have this problem of brakes grinding from the driver side wheel. All parts are new. Wheel bearing, brake pad clips. Brake pad, rotor, tyres. Still grinding  noise. The noise goes away after 1/2 hr driving. Went through a lot of mechanics. Finally find out that there is some play in the rotor, when checked, slight wiggle in the right side of rotor. My question. Do I need a new hub, one mechanic says wheel hub is bent while the dealership says may be the wheel bearing collapsed. No sound of wheel bearing when car is driving  or turning. Very quiet on highway. Very bad grinding noise from the wheel when brakes are applied otherwise no sound. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

The grinding noise is usually from brake pads (being worn) backing plate rubbing on the rotor metal. If not, then it is a wheel hub bearing fail issue. The mechanic is probably right, and you should repair the wheel hub.

Comment: OP clearly stated the brake pads are new.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just 2 questions. 1. If the wheel bearing is bad then why there is no sound of bad bearing such as while driving on high speed or when turning. The wheel itself has no play. 2. Why the noise goes away after 1/2 hr driving, if it is a bad bearing sound should stay at all times. The grinding noice is only whne the car is cold.